# Copy a row based on value but delete the row if value has changed

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in excel. "Progress Report" & "Suspense"

Currently I have a few lines of code that find everything in "Column B" of the "Progress Report" Sheet and if it contains the phrase "App Submitted" it copies it over to suspense.

```
Sub CopyNewRow()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim j1 As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet


Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Progress Report")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Suspense")

j = 2
For Each c In Source.Range("B1:B50000")   '
    If c = "App Submitted" Then
       Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
       j = j + 1


    End If

Next c
```

End Sub

However, I need to run an If statement to check if "Column B" does not contain "App Submitted" anymore, and if it doesn't remove the entire row from the "Suspense" Sheet. I am at a very beginner level of coding but I attempted to make the code work how I planned. I added this under the other if statement. Should I make this function as a new sub and then make a master sub and call them both to run at the same time?

```
'check if Progress Report still has App Submitted in Column B
  and if it was changed, delete it from suspense page'
       If Target.Rows <> Source.Rows Then
       Target.EntireRow.Delete
       j1 = j - 1**
```

I don't mind reading articles that are relevant to this topic as I do want to learn how to code visual basic with a bit more confidence, however, I am not sure of the rigt way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a unique ID, it would be easier to identify which row needs to be deleted from the Suspense sheet, but what the code below will do is, loop through Progress Report and clear everything on Suspense before copying the rows that have "App Submitted" to Suspense:

```
Sub CopyNewRow()
Dim c As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim j1 As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet: Set Source = Worksheets("Progress Report")
Dim Target As Worksheet: Set Target = Worksheets("Suspense")
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long

LastRow = Source.Cells(Source.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
'check how many rows with data on Column B of Source sheet
Target.Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
'delete everything on Suspense before copying App Submitted across
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Source.Cells(i, 2) = "App Submitted" Then
        LastRow2 = Target.Cells(Target.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        'check the last row with data on Suspense
        'Source.Rows(i).Copy Target.Rows(LastRow2 + 1) 'copy to next free row on Suspense
        Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 1) = Source.Cells(i, 1)
        Target.Cells(LastRow2 + 1, 2) = Source.Cells(i, 2)
        'above copy cells 1 & 2, (ie, A & B) from Source into Target
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: that works perfectly. Thank you!

I have a follow up question which is - Instead of copying the whole row, how could I make it so it only copied column "A" & "B" - Would that have something to do with the "source.rows" syntax?

I understand that I'm pretty much asking for the answer (sorry, don't intend to be a help vampire) but I can't quite seem to find out how to do it via google. Even if there's an article I can read to help me learn. I would appreciate that a lot. But there's no pressure :D